# Как вывести локацию телефона на карту OSM?

Tags: javascript, геолокация, openstreetmap

Подскажите код или мануал с кодом как вывести геолокацию пользователя на OSM
Имею приложение, что запрашивает отслеживание местоположения при использовании приложения.

как вывести местоположение на OSM?

ПС. Может чайниковый вопрос, но я в интернете решения не нашел особо, кроме ссылки https://habr.com/ru/articles/532902/